# What means "document popularity" in Solr

Tags: solr, document, edismax

What is ***document popularity*** in solr indexing..?

EDisMax parser uses boost parameter. In the example `&boost=popularity` like that I noticed one query. I couldn't understand what is ***boost*** as well as ***boost=popularity***. Before understanding the boost parameter I'd like to know what is "popularity" in document indexing.

Answer (score 3):

`popularity` is just "some field" which has been used as an example while `boost` is a query parameter defined for the `edismax` request handler. Boosting means to influence the scoring (the relevance of each search hit) depending on some field value (or result of some function based on field values).

See section `The boost Parameter` in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser.

If you want to implement something like `popularity` in your own index you would have to:

1. add a field to your schema called `popularity` with type `int` or `float` or `ExternalFileField` (depends on how you index and apply it).
2. gather statistics data for your search results and store those in relation to the document IDs (e.g. by evaluating access logs)
3. during index time or via `ExternalFileField` (or in the future via `docValues` partial updates) store the popularity values that you get from your statistics data.
4. apply the boost during query time by setting the parameter `boost=popularity` (or using `popularity` in a function query).

More on popularity boosting:

https://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/potter-timothy-boosting-documents-in-solr

docValues partial update:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5944

ExternalFileField:
http://www.findwise.com/blog/externalfilefield-in-solr/

Answer (score 1):

[Boosting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Boosting_Ranking_Terms) is used to increase the score of the certain documents. You can use index time boosting or query time boosting. For index time boosting you can set `boost` attribute and value to the document you index. For query time boosting you can either boost field by setting your boost value, or you can use predefined function queries.

For more information about boosting check [documents in Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_increase_the_score_for_specific_documents).

**boost=popularity** means that documents popularity is calculated in the external field (using [ExternalFileField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html)) and used to increase the score by using popularity value. Popularity of the documents can be calculated using the view count or any other parameters you want.For more about boosting documents by popularity you can [check this document](http://www.slideshare.net/LucidImagination/boosting-documents-in-solr-by-recency-popularity-and-user-preferences).

Comment: very vague , boost=popularity has not been explained , how do you set the popularity of a document in Solr.